# Using FileWriter to convert Google Analytics data into CSV file using JAVA

Tags: java, csv, google-analytics-api, filewriter

Hi all after getting some advice, I am attempting to use the filewriter method in order to export my google analytics queries that i got to a CSV file format here is what i have so far

```
   private static void printGaData(GaData results) {

   try {
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.csv")));
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

    System.out.println(
        "printing results for profile: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());

    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

      // Print column headers.
      for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
        System.out.printf(header.getName() + ", ");
      }
      System.out.println();

      // Print actual data.
      for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
        for (String column : row) {
          pw.printf(row + ", ");
        }
        pw.println();
      }

     pw.println();

    }

  }
}
```

doesnt output any data and keeps saying that the pw is non extent and stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PrintWriter is inside the try catch block.  If you define it outside like

`PrintWriter pw = null;
 try {
  pw = new PrintWriter(BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.csv")));
 } catch (Exception e) {
  // handle exception
 }`

then it will be available to the rest of your code.

Comment: ok i just did that and it is giving me an error on the pw line that says " Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "=", delete this token
 - The method BufferedWriter(FileWriter) is undefined for the       type"
I am very new to java thanks